# How to change data of UICollectionView on button click ios?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to change `UICollectionViewCell` data on button click(in iPad)?
How to achieve this?
How to send different `array count` to `numberOfItemsInSection` on button Click?

In my `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.collectionViewImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",nil] ;
```

Then in `CollectionViewMethods`:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
     return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [_collectionViewImages count];

}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UICollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];


   NSString *collectionViewImageName=[self.collectionViewImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   UIImageView * collectionImage = (UIImageView*)[myCell viewWithTag:11];

  collectionImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:collectionViewImageName];

 return myCell;
}
```

Then on ButtonClick--
(As there are 4-5 buttons i am collecting tag of each button in `NSInteger` and using that property in `numberOfItemsInSection`  like this,

```
-(void)btnTapped:(id)sender{
int tag= [(UIButton *)sender tag];
NSLog(@"Button Pressed%d",tag);
_buttonIndex=tag;
//_buttonIndex is NSInteger property
//If i add object in NSMutableArray and call reloadData my UI hangs here only.
//If  I empty my NSMutableArray and add new objects in it and then call reloadData, I am getting NSRangeException. 
}
```

And now i am using this property in `numberOfItemsInSection` as...

```
if (_buttonIndex==1){

     [collectionImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[_array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
     //My _array1 has 4 objects and my collectionViewImages array has 7 objects.

    }
```

i am getting error message as

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
```

Comment: You have to update the data source method which return the appropriate value when needed

Comment: call [myCollectionview reloadData] after you change your data source

Comment: Change `UICollectionView` datasource and call `reloadData` on it. Or do you mean to ask something else?

Comment: If you are new to using `UICollectionView` go through its [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012860) and [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: whare is your second array data?

Comment: i uploaded my answer please take a look

Comment: please show us `ButtonClick` method.

Comment: @OmerObaid Sir I edited my question ,Please have a look

Comment: @SahebSingh can you check this `[_array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is this valid or not

Comment: @OmerObaid my program stops on the same line.What to do?

Comment: @SahebSingh check array count and indexPath.row

Comment: @OmerObaid Can You Explain Me sir,Where i am wrong??

Comment: @OmerObaid- The stupidity which I was doing that ,I created the `property` for `UICollectionView` but forgot to connect with Interface Builder. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're just simply asking how to add/remove data from a UICollectionView through an IBAction. You would just add an object to your `UICollectionView's` datasource and reload. Here is an example of adding something:

```
-(IBAction)addObject:(id)sender {
  [self.objectArray addObject:@"new object"];
  [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Actually i am trying to add objects to array in my viewDidLoad.
and pass the arrayCount in numberOfItemsInSection.
When i change the array elements on buttonClick method and call reload on it,It is giving me NSRangeException. I am not understanding what to do?

Comment: @SahebSingh then you better show us that error and post your code rather then asking how to update. Edit your question and post buttonClick function

Comment: @SahebSingh have you alloc'd your datasource array in `viewDidLoad`? Are you referencing the array's `count` property anywhere in your code?

Comment: @JMarsh Yes alloc'd my datasource array in ViewDidLoad

Comment: The stupidity which I was doing that ,I created the `property` for `UICollectionView` but forgot to connect with Interface Builder. :p

Comment: Ah, haha. It happens to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

well you keep two array with a BOOL and based on taps you relload the UicollectionView first keep two array

Declare BOOL

```
BOOL isChangeData;
```

Ex :

```
 self.collectionViewImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",nil] ;

 self.collectionViewImages1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"4.jpg",@"5.jpg",@"6.jpg",nil] ;

 isChangeData = TRUE;
```

First time set original Data as Datasource

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(isChangeData){

    isChangeData = false;

    return [_collectionViewImages1 count];
     }

else{

    isChangeData = TRUE;

    return [_collectionViewImages count];
}

}
```

in button action Make BOOL true and reload UICOllectionView

```
-(IBAction)changeData:(id)sender {

 [self.CollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this Works if i did any mistake pls correct me.

Comment: Brilliant! Absolutely saved my life! The one thing I would add is that, if youw anted to get back to the original collectionView you could create something like -(IBAction)originalData:(id)sender { isChangeData = FALSE; [self.CollectionView reloadData]; } otherwise isChangeData would remain true no matter how many times you reloaded.

Comment: @mysticcola Hey, thanks for letting me know the mistake i did and now I have changed the code. Now hope code looks ok and now it will reload with different data. And Happy that it's helped you.